# love2d play a sound twice?

Tags: audio, playback, love2d

I have a problem with playing sounds.

The purpose is making a text to speech program that talks with my voice.

I recorded a lot of phonemes (.wav files with parts of speech) that need to play after each other in the right order.
each sound must play ONLY if the previous sound finished playing.
so if my program needs to say 'hello' then it does this:

```
**play("h.wav")
if "h.wav":isStopped() then:
play("e.wav")
if "e.wav":isStopped() then... etc ...**
```

For test purposes i want to play "a.wav" twice but the problem is that i only hear 'A' once...
if i play e.g. 'A' and then 'B', it works fine..

Any help would be mush appreciated!

This is the test code i currently have:

```
function love.load()
voice = {"a","b","e","f", ......}
for i in pairs(voice) do
voice[i] = love.audio.newSource("VOICE/" .. voice[i] .. ".wav", "static")
end
end

function love.keypressed(key)
if key == "a" then
voice[1]:play()
while voice[1]:isPlaying() do end
voice[1]:play()
while voice[1]:isPlaying() do end
end
end
```

Comment: I tried your code, and tried my best, but I guess this is a Love2D bug. If I try with voice[1], then voice[2], and then voice[1] again, it works. I think you should report this to http://love2d.org

Comment: Thanks for trying, i also tough it was a bug, regards

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, what if you tried this:

```
if ( voice[ 1 ]:isPlaying() ) then
    voice[ 1 ]:stop()
    voice[ 1 ]:play()
end
```

I guess you could do that before playing any sound.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i immediately see an error in your suggestion code: if the first sound is playing it immediately stops playing and plays again, the catch is to make it wait until it is fully finished and THEN play it again... i think its a bug in a sound dll of love2d.  when a source has finished playing, and you play it again (with :play), it sometimes returns false on :isPlaying - as a result, some words were being skipped if you used them twice on the same phrase...

Comment: ow, i see what you are trying to say. yes i could try that but i hoped there was a clean solution for this, maybe some other dll i could use for the sounds? (the sounds need to play quickly after each other (and loaded in ram) because its for text to speech purposes..)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play the same sound twice simultaneously, you'll need to have multiple instances of the source.

SLAM, an audio manager library for Löve2D, handles this perfectly.

https://love2d.org/wiki/SLAM

Here's an example with SLAM that will play the same sound multiple times :

```
require("slam")

sounds = {
  ["testAudio"] = love.audio.newSource("testAudio.wav", "stream"),
}

for i = 1, 10 do
  sounds["testAudio"]:play()
end
```

This way, any instance that's currently being played will not be stopped.

Comment: Ulydev, NOT simultaneously..., play it twice but don't let it overlap or stop the previous sound. but thanks for the link, still interesting for another project.